# How could I set 2 depth android project dependencies in ADT?

Tags: android, adt, actionbarsherlock

I like using ActionBarSherlock for my projects. 
In these day, I want to make my repeatable code to library.

Currently, I have been set up and used my projects with this documents 'Managing Projects from Eclipse with ADT'
 * http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

In this time, my projects are have these dependencies.

- ActionBarSherlock

  - MyProject1
  - MyProject2
  - MyProject3

I want to change like below

- ActionBarSherlock (is Library)

  - MyCommonComponent (is Library)

    - MyProject1
    - MyProject2
    - MyProject3

Because MyProjectX series have almost same codes that have depend ActionBarSherlock.

So I set up. But ADT show some errors.

If I turn on library option for MyCommonComponent, 
ADT show this errors during MyProject1 compiling time.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/actionbarsherlock/R
```

Because of ActionBarSherlock resources embedded through dependency setting, ADT show duplication class importing error.

Do you have any solution about this situation?

I mean "Could a library project depend on another library project?"

Comment: Is `ActionBarSherlock` added as library to `MyProjectX` ?

Comment: What Android SDK & ADT version do you use?

Comment: I think easy expression about this situation. "Could a library project depend on another library project?"

Comment: @yorkw ADT 19. I always endeavor to use recent version

Comment: _"Could a library project depend on another library project?"_ Yes. I guess your probably add both ActionBarSherlock and MyCommonComponent library reference to MyProject1. Try removing ActionBarSherlock library reference from MyProject1.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you make incorrect referencing of the libraries. If I get you correctly your current project setup is like that:

```
ActionBarSherlock (is Library)
 |    MyCommonComponent (is Library)
 |---|----MyProject1
 |---|----MyProject2
 |---|----MyProject3
```

Meaning that you try to have every project referencing both libraries, not only the one on the top level. However I think the correct setup is like:

```
ActionBarSherlock (is Library)
 |----MyCommonComponent (is Library)
      |---MyProject1
      |---MyProject2
      |---MyProject3
```

I.e only `MyCommonComponent` referencing `ActionBarSherlock` and all the others referencing just `MyCommonComponent`.